# How do I load all available images with Owl Carousel so I dont have to hit the right arrow to reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

On version 1.3.3 of the owl carousel how can I load all available images so that I dont have to hit the right arrow to load more.  I want them to all be loaded so there is no jump when I scroll.

I dont see an option to load all instead of swiping through4 and having to reload with clicking the arrow.

```
$.fn.owlCarousel.options = {

        items : 5,
        itemsCustom : false,
        itemsDesktop : [1199, 4],
        itemsDesktopSmall : [979, 3],
        itemsTablet : [768, 2],
        itemsTabletSmall : false,
        itemsMobile : [479, 1],
        singleItem : false,
        itemsScaleUp : false,

        slideSpeed : 200,
        paginationSpeed : 800,
        rewindSpeed : 1000,

        autoPlay : false,
        stopOnHover : false,

        navigation : false,
        navigationText : ["prev", "next"],
        navigationMargin : 0,
        rewindNav : true,
        scrollPerPage : false,

        pagination : true,
        paginationNumbers : false,

        responsive : true,
        responsiveRefreshRate : 200,
        responsiveBaseWidth : window,

        baseClass : "owl-carousel",
        theme : "owl-theme",

        lazyLoad : false,
        lazyFollow : true,
        lazyEffect : "fade",

        autoHeight : false,

        jsonPath : false,
        jsonSuccess : false,

        dragBeforeAnimFinish : true,
        mouseDrag : true,
        touchDrag : true,

        addClassActive : false,
        transitionStyle : false,

        beforeUpdate : false,
        afterUpdate : false,
        beforeInit : false,
        afterInit : false,
        beforeMove : false,
        afterMove : false,
        afterAction : false,
        startDragging : false,
        afterLazyLoad: false
    };
```

Comment: please post your minimal code example so we can see what's wromg with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `lazyFollow` to `false` as well:

```
...
lazyLoad : false,
lazyFollow : false, // <<<--
...
```